# Unsupported GeoJSON type

Tags: openlayers, geojson, php

I run a query and I get a GeoJSON file, but when I try to load the file into the map, I get the error that it's an **Unsuported GeoJSON type**.
this is the PHP file that generate GeoJSON :

```
$element = $_POST['element'];

$query = "SELECT one, two, three, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 7) AS geojson FROM TABLE WHERE parcel = '$parcel'";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

$geojson = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => array()
);
$i = 0;
while ($line = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $feature = array(
    'geometry' => json_decode($line['geojson'], true),
    'properties' => $data[]=$line,
    'id' => $i++
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}
$localData = json_encode($geojson);

//$contData = "data/fileData_".session_id().".json";
$contData = "data/fileData.json";

$file = fopen($contData, "w");

fwrite($file, $localData);
fclose($file);
```

and the file is like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "crs": {
          "type": "name",
          "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:25830"
          }
        },
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                628354.2325,
                4630884.3655
              ],
              [
                628340.7125,
                4630906.3255
              ],
              [
                628344.293,
                4630942.2755
              ],
              [
                628344.673,
                4630946.0955
              ],
              [
                628352.403,
                4630943.3355
              ],
              [
                628378.293,
                4630938.4055
              ],
              [
                628427.4635,
                4630932.5155
              ],
              [
                628453.3535,
                4630928.2655
              ],
              [
                628536.7735,
                4630913.475
              ],
              [
                628555.6835,
                4630910.325
              ],
              [
                628556.4135,
                4630908.665
              ],
              [
                628557.2335,
                4630906.775
              ],
              [
                628559.8935,
                4630900.655
              ],
              [
                628562.8335,
                4630893.935
              ],
              [
                628565.553,
                4630884.025
              ],
              [
                628568.773,
                4630867.435
              ],
              [
                628571.8625,
                4630851.215
              ],
              [
                628578.6825,
                4630828.435
              ],
              [
                628586.3525,
                4630810.605
              ],
              [
                628580.442,
                4630804.225
              ],
              [
                628579.812,
                4630798.165
              ],
              [
                628575.472,
                4630792.465
              ],
              [
                628569.952,
                4630788.665
              ],
              [
                628555.922,
                4630778.625
              ],
              [
                628546.3315,
                4630771.655
              ],
              [
                628530.4115,
                4630760.435
              ],
              [
                628508.971,
                4630744.875
              ],
              [
                628505.081,
                4630743.235
              ],
              [
                628498.651,
                4630743.425
              ],
              [
                628492.501,
                4630743.695
              ],
              [
                628447.621,
                4630754.185
              ],
              [
                628434.221,
                4630756.635
              ],
              [
                628415.461,
                4630756.675
              ],
              [
                628398.861,
                4630751.805
              ],
              [
                628369.832,
                4630833.995
              ],
              [
                628369.122,
                4630836.275
              ],
              [
                628354.4225,
                4630883.7955
              ],
              [
                628354.2325,
                4630884.3655
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": "25",
        "cadastralcode": "50010A00700271",
        "parcel": "271",
        "zone": "300-400",
        "longitude": "41.819076014660794",
        "latitude": "-1.4532398649376337",
        "altitude": "364",
        "geojson": "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"crs\":{\"type\":\"name\",\"properties\":{\"name\":\"EPSG:25830\"}},\"coordinates\":[[[[628354.2325,4630884.3655],[628340.7125,4630906.3255],[628344.293,4630942.2755],[628344.673,4630946.0955],[628352.403,4630943.3355],[628378.293,4630938.4055],[628427.4635,4630932.5155],[628453.3535,4630928.2655],[628536.7735,4630913.475],[628555.6835,4630910.325],[628556.4135,4630908.665],[628557.2335,4630906.775],[628559.8935,4630900.655],[628562.8335,4630893.935],[628565.553,4630884.025],[628568.773,4630867.435],[628571.8625,4630851.215],[628578.6825,4630828.435],[628586.3525,4630810.605],[628580.442,4630804.225],[628579.812,4630798.165],[628575.472,4630792.465],[628569.952,4630788.665],[628555.922,4630778.625],[628546.3315,4630771.655],[628530.4115,4630760.435],[628508.971,4630744.875],[628505.081,4630743.235],[628498.651,4630743.425],[628492.501,4630743.695],[628447.621,4630754.185],[628434.221,4630756.635],[628415.461,4630756.675],[628398.861,4630751.805],[628369.832,4630833.995],[628369.122,4630836.275],[628354.4225,4630883.7955],[628354.2325,4630884.3655]]]]}"
      },
      "id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In creating your GeoJSON, you forgot to add `type` property for your feature: `"type" : "Feature"`, so it should be:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
.
.
.
```

That's how it looks like then:

[image]

Comment: what do you use to see it?  because it doesn't load it on the map for me. It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't load it on the map...

Comment: There is no code in your question of how you are trying to display it, so that's again new question. But one thing is for sure: since it's in EPSG:25830, you have to use proj4 to define projection and then use it when reading GeoJSON to convert coordinates to standard EPSG:3857.

Comment: See my modified answer to your original question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385490/loading-a-dynamic-geojson-created-from-a-postgresql-query